# call DB2 stored proc with output params from non-specific query tool

Tags: db2, parameter-passing, db2-400

I have a customer that built a proc in her DB (I believe it is DB2) with some custom tool. the proc has 1 input and 6 output params and I think it is a pretty basic lookup function that could probably be done easier with a simple select statement. My company uses a third-party db connection tool that only allows plain text queries, there is no chance of registering output variables as I am accustomed. Is there plain-text-friendly method to call a proc with output params?

```
call absproc (45634.21, out1, out2, out3, out4, out5, out6)
```

Follow up question: is there a simple query tool I can use to simulate this that might give me more meaningful error messages? my third-party db connection keeps giving me generic messages "the connection has closed" and i suspect db2 would give me a better message, like "number of parameters don't match".

Comment: What is a _"plain text query"_ ? Do you mean your query-tool is unable to parse 'CALL' as plain text, or just unable to handle output-parameters?

Comment: I mean my query tool isn't going to parse the text I pass in any way and treats the db engine as a black box. I can't pass variables to it that will be filled with the output params.

Comment: What is the Db2-server platform (z/os,  i-series,  linux/unix/windows/cloud)? Please tag one of db2-zos, db2400, db2-luw.

Comment: You may wrap your SP call into a compound statement, if your tool is able to call it. Like `BEGIN DECLARE out1 SOME_DATA_TYPE DEFAULT const1; ...; CALL abcproc (1, out1, ...); END`.

Comment: Db2-for-i (as/400) supports compound-sql, e.g. anonymous blocks, so you could wrap the sproc as mentioned above although you still need a way to view the resulting variables. Another way is to wrap the sproc from another sproc that returns a result-set which comprises the values returned by the output-parameters of the nested call to ABSPROC.  Much depends on your skillset and competence. Far easier to get your customer to do that work, __OR__ discard your limited toolset and use a proper toolset instead.

Comment: @mao, this is on i-series, im not sure which of those tags apply, but I don't think I'm interacting with the OS, so not sure it should matter.

Comment: It matters because some platforms do not support anonymous blocks (e.g. db2 for z/os). You should __always__ specify your Db2-server platform  __and__ your Db2-server _version_ because the answer can depend on those facts!

Comment: @MarkBarinstein begin declare out1 char(15) ... call abcproc (123.45, out1 ...) select out1 end -- something like that?

Comment: BEGIN 
 declare rtncode char(15)
 declare acctnbr char(17)
 declare zipcode char(5)
 declare acctsts char(1)
 declare refNum char(10)
 declare accttype char(1)
 call SLSFILES.EPPSIVR (8000001.73, rtncode, acctnbr, zipcode, acctsts, refNum, accttype)
 select rtncode as rtncode, zipcode as zipcode
END
tried and got the same error. does this syntax look correct? my error has no useful info

Comment: @JaredH Don't try to run `SELECT whatever` at the end. Db2 doesn't support "selects into nothing" in the routines or compound statements. And every statement inside the compound block must be enclosed by `;`. If you want to get an output parameter value, use another technique like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/KqEih9Ws), for example.